# Without primary key in source and destination table how to append new rows that are added in source table + SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Without primary key in source and destination table, how to append new rows that are added in source table + SSIS package

Comment: This is not a free code writing service - though you might get lucky. In addition, no one can see your data or your schema. How do you "know" that any given row has been added? Do not assume that you can rely on any order of appearance within a table - absent a set of columns that defines insert order there is no mechanism to determine this attribute. If you want help, you will need to make an effort yourself to allows others to evaluate your issue. You will also need to consider the effects of dml operations on the destination if that is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the source output through a LOOKUP Transformation and basically match with the destination table on each column one after the other.
You have to select “Redirect Rows To NoMatch Output” in the Lookup task so that all records in the source that did not match with the destination are redirected to the NoMatch output and the NoMatch output is inserted into the destination table.